# How can I delete files that are not used in code files in linux?

Tags: linux, grep, find, rm

I am running Fedora 18 linux and I have a PHP project that I have been working on for some time.  I am trying to clean things up for a production deploy of a web application.  I have a folder of icon images that over time has collected files that are not used in my code any more, either because I changed to a different icon in code, or the image file was used to create other icons.  What I am looking to do is to make a backup copy of the entire code project, and HOPEFULLY using a combination of `find`, `rm` and `grep` on the command line, scan the entire folder of the images, and if the images are not used anywhere in my code files, delete them. I did some searching on the web and I am finding things that find a line of text in a file and delete it, but I have not found anything quite like what I am trying to do.

Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

So here is what I came up with.  I put together a shell script that does what I need.  For the benefit of those who stumble upon this, and for those who want to critique my solution, here it is. I chose to skip files that were found in .xcf files because these are only used to create many of the icon files and some of the .png images would grep to these .xcf files.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/var/www/html/support_desk/templates/default/images/icons/*
codedir=/var/www/html/support_desk_branch/

for f in $FILES
do
  bn=$(basename $f)

  ext="${bn##*.}"

  echo "Processing $bn file..."

  if ! fgrep --quiet -R $bn $codedir; then
    if [ ext != 'xcf' ]; then
      rm $f
    fi
  fi

done
```

Now I have ONLY the image files that are used in the PHP script files.  Just so as not to miss any of the icon files used in the menu, which is defined in a table in a mysql database, I created an sql dump file of the data for that table, and put it in the path of the application files prior to running the shell script.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to find unused icon files would be to do a build of your complete project and then look at the access-times of the icon-files.  Those that were not read recently (including with grep, of course) would show up readily.

For instance, supposing that you did a backup an hour ago, and did a build ten minutes ago — the access times would be distinct.  Then

```
find . -amin +15 -type f
```

should give a nice list of "unused" files.  If you're sure of the list (you did do a backup, right?) then you could purge the unused files:

```
find . -amin +15 -type f -exec rm -i {} \;
```

If you are *really* certain, you can remove the `-i` option.

Comment: My only issue with this is, as I mentioned, there are files that were used to create other icon files that I want removed, and many of these have been accessed recently.  That is why I thought of GREPing the file names with all of the code files to see if they exist anywhere in the code files.  I am just not sure the best way to do it.   With 395 files in the folder, to go through each one individually would take a LOT of time.

Comment: But since you know *when* you accessed the files, you can design a suitable threshold for pruning out files which have not been accessed recently.

Comment: As I have said, there are 395 icon files.  If I haven't worked on or accessed a module in a while, your solution will remove needed files. Any way you go with your solution, there are going to be files that should be included for the application that will get deleted, and files that are not needed that will remain.  See my solution below.  It does EXACTLY what I said I needed and I don't need to design any thresholds.  I just tell it the folder where the image files are, and the folder where the code files are to search, and in less than a minute I have what I need.